# Objective-C Regular Expression

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, regex, nsregularexpression

I need a Regular Expression in Objective C to accept either `male` or `female` only..it should be `case-Insensitive` means can accept lower as well as upper .I gone through apple documents..and Implemented below code but not working...

--> **male or Female** can only be accepted

```
-(BOOL)genderValidate:(NSString *)string{

NSError *error=nil;

NSRegularExpression *regex =[NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\b (m|f)(a|e)(l|m)(e|a)(l)(e) \\b" options:(NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive) error: &error];
NSUInteger numberofmatches =[regex numberOfMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0,[string length])];

return numberofmatches;


}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why use a regular expression? Keep it simple:

```
- (BOOL)genderValidate:(NSString *)string {
    string = [string lowercaseString];

    return [string isEqualToString:@"male"] || [string isEqualToString:@"female"];
}
```

Comment: The question specifies that "it should be case-Insensitive" so you probably want to use `caseInsensitiveCompare:` instead of `isEqualToString`.

Comment: @user1135469 Please look at my code again. The first line converts `string` to all lowercase. The result is a case-insensitive comparison.

Comment: Sorry...my bad (I guess it deserves an upvote now :D). However there is always the option of removing the first line and using `caseInsensitiveCompare:`

Comment: @user1135469 Yes, that would be an option.

Answer (score 1):

regex should be

```
^(male|female)$
```

Comment: and if need vale upto three digits...then `^[0-9][0-9][0-9]$` ryt?

Comment: @Christien yes.. you can also try `^[0-9]{3}$` or `\d{3}` ^ means start of the string..`$` means end of the string!

Comment: @Christien That will check for a value this is exactly 3 digits. No more. No less. If you want to check for 1, 2, or 3 digits, then use: ^[0-9]{1,3}$